# Add function to NodeJs console typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, typescript-typings

I added function `red` to Node's `console`
But how let typescript know it ?

```
import chalk from "chalk";
const red = (text: unknown[]) => chalk.red(...text);
console["red"] = red;
```

I tried

```
// console.d.ts
declare namespace NodeJS {
    interface ConsoleConstructor {
        red: (text: unknown[]) => void;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can re-declare the type of console:

```ts
declare const console: ConsoleExtension

interface ConsoleExtension extends Console {
  red(text: unknown[]): unknown
}
```